# Performing str.split on a column in a dataframe returns a SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am attempting to split a column and keep only the third item as the column value using the following

```
df1['gene_name'] = df1.loc[:,'gene_name'].str.split(';', expand=True)[2]
```

I have also tried these variations

```
df1['gene_name'] = df1.iloc[:,'gene_name'].str.split(';', expand=True)[2]

df1['gene_name'] = df1.loc[:,'gene_name'].str.split(';', expand=True)[2]

df1['gene_name'] = df1['gene_name'].str.split(';', expand=True)[2]

df1['gene_name'] = df1.gene_name.str.split(';', expand=True)[2]
```

But it always returns this warning

```
find_target_genes.py:19: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df1['gene_name'] = df1.loc[:,'gene_name'].str.split(';', expand=True)[2]
```

I have also tried using 4 (column index) instead of gene_names but this results in an error.

How can I make this work?
I've looked through the documentation but I don't think I am fully understanding it since I can't figure out whats wrong.

Here is an example of 2 of the columns I am trying to split (yes this is all in one column):

```
ID "A" ; version "B" ; name "C" ; source "D' ;  transcript "C"
ID "A1" ; version "B1" ; name "C1" ; source "D1" ;  transcript "C1"
```

I would like the column to say `name "C"`  only and get rid of the rest

Comment: How about putting `df1 = df1.copy()` right after creation of `df1`?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: I'm still not clear on how to use this and having trouble following the linked post. I tried putting this as a separate line above my code and adding `.copy()` on to the end of my code. Both ways returned the same error.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not on the right side of the assignment, it is in the left one. You are using `df1['gene_name']` instead of `df1.loc[:,'gene_name']` as is recommended on the [User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). Using your assignment, "it’s very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy". Depending on the "memory layout of the array" bad things can happen. So, you should be doing:

```py
df1.loc[:,'gene_name'] = df1.loc[:,'gene_name'].str.split(';', expand=True)[2]
```

Comment: Any of the options give me an error using pandas 1.0.3. Do you have a sample that gives you the error to test?

Comment: I have edited the question to include an example of the column I am attempting to split. I did not include the other columns in the data set but I don't think they are relevant to the error.

Comment: I have tried without error `df1 = DataFrame([['ID \"A\" ; version \"B\" ; name \"C\" ; source \"D\" ;  transcript \"C\"'],['ID \"A1\" ; version \"B1\" ; name \"C1\" ; source \"D1\" ;  transcript \"C1\"']],columns=['gene_name'])` and `df1['gene_name'] = df1.loc[:,'gene_name'].str.split(';', expand=True)[2]`

Comment: Thanks for Fregui.
In my case, the warning disappeared when I replace it from both sides of the equation 
so "df.loc used in both sides...df.loc[:,'column_name']".

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you use `.assign()`, that warning goes away. See code below:

```
df.assign(gene_name = df['gene_name'].str.split(';').str[2])
```

Comment: that is because ``assign`` creates a new dataframe

Comment: hmm this runs fine but doesn't actually preform the split. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the warning disappeared when I replace it from both sides of the equation so "df.loc used in both sides...df.loc[:,'column_name']".